# FullCalendar how to use refetchResources?

Tags: php, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

Been trying to figure this out all day. I have a calendar with resources as employees and on load everything works fine.
What I'm trying to do is filter the employees so only the selected show by the users selection with a external filter.

If i need to I can create some kind of jQuery functions and make it work. But doesn't seem ideal and not sure how much it can scale.

Here' what I have now, and like I said works onload:

```
resources: function(dataInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
       successCallback(data);
              });
          },
```

The data is a object of the employees

I have a side menu that has multiple select to one, two or All employees.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <h5> @lang('modules.tasks.assignTo')</h5>
                          <select class="select2 select2-multiple user_id" multiple="multiple"
                                  data-placeholder="@lang('modules.tasks.chooseAssignee')" name="user_id[]" id="user_id">
                                <option value="all" selected="selected">@lang('app.all')</option>
                                  @foreach($crew_leaders as $employee)
                                      @php  $selected = ''; @endphp
                                      <option {{ $selected }} value="{{ $employee->id }}">{{ ucwords($employee->first_name) ?? '---' }} {{ ucwords($employee->last_name) ?? '---' }} </option>
                                  @endforeach
                          </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

So on select it needs to update the employee resources. I've include an image for more clarity.

Thanks in advance

[image: employee filter]

Comment: So have you got some code which handles the event when the user selects someone from the list? It's not clear if you've got as far as that yet, or whether the problem is more about how to integrate that with fullCalendar.

Comment: @ADyson Got it working. Thanks for looking. BTW I have the event handled was just looking to filter the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, not sure if it's the best solution but it works.

In Calendar Class I added

```
          var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    .....
          resourceAreaWidth: "22%",
          resources: function(dataInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            var sel = $('#user_id').val();
            if(sel != null && sel.length > 0)
            {
              if(sel.includes('all') === true && sel.length == 1){
                 successCallback(getCrew(['all']));
              }else{
                 successCallback(getCrew(sel));
              }
            }
          },
          resourceOrder: 'title'
    ...
    });
```

Then created a function getCrew()

```
      function getCrew(data=[]){
                        
      var url = "{{ route('admin.activities.all-activities.filterActivities') }}";
      var crew = '';
    
      $.easyAjax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: url,
          async: false, //<-- Make sure this is set to false
          data: {data:data, type:'crew'},
          success: function (response) {
             if (response.status == "success") {
//            //return data to post to resorce
                crew = response;
             }
          }
      });
    return crew;
  }
```

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.